# How to restart the app between integration tests?

Tags: flutter, dart, testing, automated-tests, integration

How can one restart the app between integration tests that are in one file?

The goal is to wipe out any state that the app may be keeping.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Phoenix Package [Flutter Phoenix](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_phoenix)

Phoenix restarts your application at the application level, rebuilding your application widget tree from scratch, losing any previous state.

**Usage:**

Wrap your App widget in the `Phoenix` widget.

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    Phoenix(
      child: App(),
    ),
  );
}
```

Call the `rebirth` static method when you want to restart your application (rebuild the entire widget tree from scratch).

```
Phoenix.rebirth(context);
```

Comment: in `Phoenix.rebirth(context);` what is context with respective to integration tests?